# Sqlclient transaction and .Commit()

Tags: transactions, transactionscope, sqlclient

In this code will the SomeFunction() after the .commit() be considered part of the transaction? Would it rollback if something blew up? I need to do further processing after dynamic records are inserted and would prefer to do it all in one big lump.

```
command.Transaction = transaction
Try
    command.CommandText = _
    "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')"
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    transaction.Commit()
    'do a function call here
    SomeFunction()
Catch ex As Exception
    transaction.Rollback()
End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it wont rollback since by the time `Somefunction()` is called the transaction is already Commited.

However if `SomeFunction` throws any exception your catch block will still throw an exception in the `transaction.Rollback()` method as there is no active transaction to rollback.

You should move your `Somefunction()` call below your Exception block and if possible put it in another try catch block.

```
command.Transaction = transaction
Try
    command.CommandText = _
    "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')"
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    transaction.Commit()

Catch ex As Exception
    transaction.Rollback()
End Try

    'do a function call here
    SomeFunction()
```

Comment: Yeh, I kind of figured. I'll to put it all in a sp like I wanted to avoid. Thanks for confirming!